# IQ scores from individuals and their siblings and/or twins

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a data set that will allow students to make heritability calculations for IQ.

It would be nice if the dataset included data on whether siblings were raised apart as well as together, but that's not essential.

Answer (score 5):

maybe check the codebooks in these public use data sets

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20study%20of%20adolescent%20to%20adult%20health%20%28addhealth%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20surveys%20%28nls%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/panel%20study%20of%20income%20dynamics%20%28psid%29

Answer (score 0):

This source looks promising https://www.twins.org.au/research/twin-and-data-resource  but I didn't investigate it to see if includes IQ data.