# Intelligence quotient (IQ) data based on birthdate and/or other factors

Tags: education

Where can I find raw intelligence quotient (IQ) data, ideally with age/birthday/etc? I followed the links in the answer to [IQ scores from individuals and their siblings and/or twins](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/iq-scores-from-individuals-and-their-siblings-and-or-twins) but nothing there appears to be helpful.

I've found and read several studies that discuss IQ-to-birthdate correlation, but many of them refer to previous studies, and I can't find the original studies and/or the actual raw data used by those original studies.

Comment: [This research](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1348/000709905X49700/abstract) was performed using [these data](https://www.abdn.ac.uk/birth-cohorts/1950s/for-researchers/data-access/). Possibly you could send them a request...